# How to center a iScroll div

Tags: javascript, iscroll

I use iScroll on div attribute, there is HTML code in Chrome Elements

```
<div id="content">
        <div class="article" id="contentWrapper" style="overflow: hidden;">
            <div id="contentScroller" style="height: 610px; 
                 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0ms; 
                  transition: -webkit-transform 0ms; 
                 -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px; 
                 -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);">
                <ul id="thelist">
                                         <li class="item">XXX</li>
                                         <li class="item">XXX</li>
                                         <li class="item">XXX</li>
                                         <li class="item">XXX</li>
                                         <li class="item">XXX</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to center contentScroller

but it not works when i add "margin:0 auto" style on contentScroller

the width of article is 1366 and contentScroller is 948

so, how to center contentScroller?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `text-align: center` on `#thelist`?

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Nz3Q7/

The style code (put this in a style sheet file):

```
#contentWrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#contentScroller {
    height: 610px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0ms;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0ms;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);
}
#thelist {
    text-align: center;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="article" id="contentWrapper">
        <div id="contentScroller">
            <ul id="thelist">
                <li class="item">XXX</li>
                <li class="item">XXX</li>
                <li class="item">XXX</li>
                <li class="item">XXX</li>
                <li class="item">XXX</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If that centering is what you want, and you need help getting the bullets removed, let me know.

Comment: The style code is not in html code...i copy that code from Chrome-tools-Elements. and there is something i forgot to tell, the li in #thelist have "float:left" style.Almost have six li in every row

Comment: Is that mandatory for some reason? It's much better practice to not put css inline.  Like consider if you had that same UL on multiple pages and wanted to change an attribute... You would have to update every page OR if it's in a separate CSS file, you edit in a single spot.

Comment: so..buddy, here is the reason, there is not one li in one row

Comment: i dont even know what to say to that, lol, but if you fixed it some how on your own then great!